# Wordpress on stage environment with SVN

Tags: load-balancing, svn, wordpress

Currently we have this configuration for our website:

**Stage** environment. On this environment we use a connection to live DB and for code we use SVN.

**Production/Live** environment. Load Balancing between multiple web servers. A storage server for images.

We are planning to install Wordpress on this configuration, but I'm not sure what would happen if a plugin would be updated on production environment? The files from Stage would be out of sync. How could we handle this? Should we exclude plugins folders from SVN? But in this case we will not be able anymore to test plugins on Stage.

What other things should we consider for such a configuration? The main goal would be to be able to test changes on Stage before we export them to live environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue but with a different CMS.

We focussed two ways:

1. Disabling updating on the live system, doing that only on the dev system, adding changes to svn and bring them to the live system
2. Writing a script watching the wordpress installation on the live system, for changes, adding them to svn and commit with an update message.

Both ways arent perfect but can work.

Comment: What about pages/posts updated on stage environment?